# In MongoDB, is there a way to update many documents and get the documents that were modified in a single call?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java-driver, mongo-java

I'm working with the Mongo Java Driver, but looking through Mongo's documentation, it doesn't look driver specific.

`update(filter, update)` can update multiple documents but returns a WriteResult which only provides flags/counts.

`findOneAndUpdate(filter, update)` returns the actual document that was modified, but it can only update one document at a time.

Is there no way to do this in one call? If not, the client would have to call `find(filter)`, then `update(filter, update)`, then `find(...)` with a new filter matching the IDs obtained in the initial find (since the update can potentially change document values that were in the initial filter).

Is there a better way?

Comment: I don't see a method to achieve that in one call... 
Java specific docs are here: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.1/apidocs/
Maybe, if you re-frame your goal you'll find alternative ways to achieve that. Like, why do you need to get only the updated documents?

Comment: Yes, I've been going over these docs (specifically the collection, but looking for others) and don't see anything that fits my description. The docs are quite large though, so it's not optimal to go through docs exhaustively and it's easy to miss something. Hence, I'm reaching out to the community

Answer (score 1):

I am unaware of any write commands that return a cursor, which is essentially what you are asking for, nor am I seeing anything relevant in driver source.